# Replace everything in line after 33rd comma

Tags: notepad++

I have a csv file open in Notepad++. The header has 33 commas, meaning it has 34 columns. However, out of 500k lines, only 7k lines have 33 commas - the other ones all have more. For each line, I need to remove everything after and incl. the 34th comma.

I have identified the lines with Search: ^[^,\n]*((,[^,\n]*){33}$)

In the Replace box, I need something like: \1 to keep the found string but how can I remove the rest?

```
^[^,\n]*((,[^,\n]*){33}$)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You"re close, with small modifications, this works:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^,\r\n]*(?:,[^,\r\n]*){33}\K.*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  [^,\r\n]*     # 0 or more any character except comma and linebreak
  (?:           # non capture group
    ,           # a comma
    [^,\r\n]*   # 0 or more any character except comma and linebreak
  ){33}         # end group, appears 33 times
  \K            # forget all we've seen until this position
  .*            # 0 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```